# How to remove straight line between co ordinates in google map path in php

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to Draw Path between start location and end location with multiple way-points on google map using java-script. The path is working but the problem is that there are several straight lines produced between the coordinate. How to remove these lines?

My code is given below..

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [
            {
                "title": 'A',
                "lat": '26.3489',
                "lng": ' 92.6845',
                "description": 'A'
            }
        ,
            {
                "title": 'B',
                "lat": '26.3546',
                "lng": '92.6902',
                "description": 'B'
            }
       ,
            {
                "title": 'D',
                "lat": '26.3508',
                "lng": '92.7102',
                "description": 'D'
            }

         ,
            {
                "title": 'E',
                "lat": '26.4285',
                "lng": '92.8497',
                "description": 'E'
            } 
        ,
          {
              "title": 'E',
              "lat": '26.5486',
              "lng": '92.9008',
              "description": 'E'
          } 
        ,
          {
              "title": 'E',
              "lat": ' 26.6567',
              "lng": '92.7717',
              "description": 'E'
          } 

         ,
            {
                "title": 'C',
                "lat": '26.807',
                "lng": '92.895',
                "description": 'C'
            }
        , 

    ];
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        //***********ROUTING****************//

        //Initialize the Path Array
        var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

        //Initialize the Direction Service
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        //Set the Path Stroke Color
        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#4986E7' });

        //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
        for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
                var src = lat_lng[i];
                var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                path.push(src);
                poly.setPath(path);
                service.route({
                    origin: src,
                    destination: des,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                }, function (result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
</div>
```

How to remove the extra straight line?

here is the sample in fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ruchs2ko/1/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of this?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including sample marker data.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836341/remove-straight-line-in-google-map-path-using-javascript