# Remove straight line in google map path using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Requerment is to  Draw Path between start location and end location with multiple way-points on google map . The path is nice but the problem is that there are several straight lines between the coordinate. 
How to remove the extra straight line betwwen the co ordinates?

My code is given below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [
            {
                "title": 'A',
                "lat": '26.3489',
                "lng": ' 92.6845',
                "description": 'A'
            }
        ,
            {
                "title": 'B',
                "lat": '26.3546',
                "lng": '92.6902',
                "description": 'B'
            }
       ,
            {
                "title": 'D',
                "lat": '26.3508',
                "lng": '92.7102',
                "description": 'D'
            }

         ,
            {
                "title": 'E',
                "lat": '26.4285',
                "lng": '92.8497',
                "description": 'E'
            } 
        ,
          {
              "title": 'E',
              "lat": '26.5486',
              "lng": '92.9008',
              "description": 'E'
          } 
        ,
          {
              "title": 'E',
              "lat": ' 26.6567',
              "lng": '92.7717',
              "description": 'E'
          } 

         ,
            {
                "title": 'C',
                "lat": '26.807',
                "lng": '92.895',
                "description": 'C'
            }
        , 

    ];
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        //***********ROUTING****************//

        //Initialize the Path Array
        var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

        //Initialize the Direction Service
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        //Set the Path Stroke Color
        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#4986E7' });

        //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
        for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
                var src = lat_lng[i];
                var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                path.push(src);
                poly.setPath(path);
                service.route({
                    origin: src,
                    destination: des,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                }, function (result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
</div>
```

here is the sample in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ruchs2ko/1/

Answer (score 5):

Don't push the `src` point on to the path out of order (the directions service is asynchronous). Remove this line:

```
path.push(src);
```

And change the code to render each directions result as a separate polyline.

Related question:

- [Inconsistent behaviour drawing a route between two points in Google Maps v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176212/inconsistent-behaviour-drawing-a-route-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ruchs2ko/5/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var markers = [{
    "title": 'A',
    "lat": '26.3489',
    "lng": ' 92.6845',
    "description": 'A'
  }, {
    "title": 'B',
    "lat": '26.3546',
    "lng": '92.6902',
    "description": 'B'
  }, {
    "title": 'D',
    "lat": '26.3508',
    "lng": '92.7102',
    "description": 'D'
  }

  , {
    "title": 'E',
    "lat": '26.4285',
    "lng": '92.8497',
    "description": 'E'
  }, {
    "title": 'E',
    "lat": '26.5486',
    "lng": '92.9008',
    "description": 'E'
  }, {
    "title": 'E',
    "lat": ' 26.6567',
    "lng": '92.7717',
    "description": 'E'
  }

  , {
    "title": 'C',
    "lat": '26.807',
    "lng": '92.895',
    "description": 'C'
  },

];
window.onload = function() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var lat_lng = new Array();
  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: data.title
    });
    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
    (function(marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })(marker, data);
  }
  map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

  //***********ROUTING****************//

  //Initialize the Direction Service
  var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
  for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
      var src = lat_lng[i];
      var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
      service.route({
        origin: src,
        destination: des,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          //Initialize the Path Array
          var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

          //Set the Path Stroke Color
          var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
            map: map,
            strokeColor: '#4986E7'
          });
          poly.setPath(path);

          for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#dvMap{
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="dvMap"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```