# Unexplained extra Polyline drawn - Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a strange scenario with regards to a `Polyline` that is being drawn on the map. Before I post the code, I'll first demonstrate what happens when I make use of the normal direction services (Both calculates the resulting disctance the same = *Total Distance: 62.734 km*):

[image]

Now, when I draw the directions myself - this straight line appears out of nowhere:

[image]

**Code snippet:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [
            {
                "lat": '-26.2036247253418',
                "lng": '28.0086193084717'
            }
        ,
            {
                "lat": '-26.1259479522705',
                "lng": '27.9742794036865'
            }
        ,
            {
                "lat": '-25.8434619903564',
                "lng": '28.2100086212158'
            }
    ];
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        var labelIndex = 0;
        var totalDistance = 0;

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        //var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title,
                label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
                //icon: image
            });
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            (function (marker, data) {
                // google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                //     infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                //     infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                // });
            })(marker, data);
        }
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        //***********ROUTING****************//

        //Initialize the Path Array
        var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

        //Initialize the Direction Service
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          setMap: map
        });

        //Set the Path Stroke Color
        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#4986E7' });

        //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
        for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
                var src = lat_lng[i];
                var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                path.push(src);
                //poly.strokeColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
                poly.setPath(path);
                service.route({
                    origin: src,
                    destination: des,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                }, function (result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                        var myroute = directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0];
                        var distance = 0;

                        for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
                            distance += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
                            //for each 'leg'(route between two waypoints) we get the distance and add it to the total
                        }

                        for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {                            
                            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                            //console.log(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance);
                        }                        
                        totalDistance += distance;
                        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = (totalDistance / 1000) + ' km';
                    }                    
                });
            }
        }        
    }
</script>
<div id="dvMap"></div>
<div><p>Total Distance: <span id="total"></span></p></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inconsistent behaviour drawing a route between two points in Google Maps v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176212/inconsistent-behaviour-drawing-a-route-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove straight line in google map path using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836341/remove-straight-line-in-google-map-path-using-javascript)

Comment: @geocodezip, seems like you're the keeper of the question or something, since you've answered it in the past and -1 all who ask it again ... keep up the good work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so to solve the problem. Just remove the following line:

Reference: [Google Documentation - Simple Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple?csw=1)

[image]

And like that, the line is gone:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you also drawing a line between the first and last poly?
You should only draw lines between poly0 and poly1, poly1 and poly2 etc. but not poly100 and poly0 (if poly100 is the last one)

That would explain the straight line going from point B to A completing the shape. you don't want to complete the shape, so stop drawing. is there no function you can set to not complete the shape?

I only know of a very expensive work around and that is to trace back in reverse order from B to A along the same route. But that is probably not what you are looking for

Comment: many thanks for the response. I have no idea whether such a method exists. Even if I can just draw a line, instead of a polyline. I totally forgot about the shape aspect o.O

Comment: http://www.cadtutor.net/tutorials/autocad/drawing_objects/draw-05.gif
This is an example of a closed and open polyline, maybe you need to set it to being an open polyline somewhere, I am not to familiar with them, but maybe you will figure it out!

Comment: Yup, thats the one I guess! Thanks!

Comment: you can hit the check mark on this answer if it helped